# ¿Como resolver este problema de report viewer, no encotrado en un aplicacion Windows Form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, reportviewer

tengo un problema. Acabo de compilar un proyecto de windows form c#, y de la carpeta debug del proyecto copie y pegue el contenido en una maquina de un cliente, pero el problema es que al abrir los reportes este me indica este error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es posible que no se haya cargado los componentes?, en mi maquina si se visualiza, pero en el cliente ya no. 
Alguna forma de solucionarlo?
Aqui les envio capturas de los agregadas en las referencias.

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer me indica otro error al indicar `copy local = true en Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common`

Abjunto la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede descargar [Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/es-ES/download/details.aspx?id=35747) o Actualizando el **dll**  `Windows.ReportViewer.Winform` o con Nuget.

Comment: En la carpeta de salida, donde te genera el ejecutable y dlls, mira a ver si no hay carpetas creadas, ve dentro de esas carpetas y mira si no hay dlls ahí.

Answer (score 0):

debes asegurarte que las librerías estén incluídas en la salida de tu ejecutable. Puedes incluir las librerías desde NuGet o bien marcas las librerías y en las propiedades seleccionas *Copia Local* = **True** (debes hacerlo de a uno).

Comment: Disculpa me podrias orientar con tu respuesta amigo? Christian

Comment: En tus referencias, haz clic derecho en la librería necesaria y abre sus propiedades. Ahí selecciona Copia Local = True. Vuelve a compilar tu aplicación y te debería funcionar correctamente.

Comment: ya lo realize, y solo me visualiza el report view, pero no me carga los datos.. me indica un error nuevo...

Answer (score 0):

Esto me paso hace poco, primero revisa que el .Net Framework de la maquina este actualizado y que en la carpeta de Debug estén las dll de los report viewer, a mi se me soluciono con el tema de las dll.